# How can I change the numeration of my TOC?

Tags: table-of-contents, titletoc

Before my introductory chapter, I have abstract etc. How can I remove these from the enumeration of the TOC, so that my into chapter becomes chapter 1?

[image]

Comment: Without seeing your source code, the answer is uncertain.  However, if you invoked these sections with a `\section` command, then invoking it instead with `\section*` will leave the section unnumbered, and thus not part of the toc.  Welcome to the site.

Comment: Thanks! I realize my post was lacking, but nevertheless I found a solution and posted it below. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes, that is the approved approach,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have resolved my issue. By removing the sections from the TOC, then adding them back like this:

```
\chapter*{Scientific Environment}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Scientific Environment}
```

[image]